# Cleaning up undefined events

Tags: visual-studio-2008, event-handling

In Visual Studio, sometimes due to unnecessary clicks on Form elements in design page, a blank event handler definition is created which we actually don't want to define. Usually we can undo our action to have this blank definition removed.

Although, keeping those won't harm the application, but it surely will make code base unnecessarily lengthy.

Is there a quick way to perform clean up on the code that would remove such blank event handler as well as remove the registering code for that event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove event handler from the source file and build the program. Event subscription line in designer-generated file is not compiled - remove it and build again. Though this is not automatic way, it can be used if you didn't execute Undo command immediately, and Undo function is not available.

Comment: Agreed, this is as good as it is going to get.  Not letting it getting out of hand is of course the better approach.

Comment: I actually knew this method anyway :). Was thinking if something better exists. I was hoping some kind of plugins could be developed that would do this task for us. I guess none exists as of this moment.